# Issue with ViewModel returning null values to View

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Most of the values in my viewmodel are being returned successfully, but after I updated my model classes, two of those values (which are tied to other tables in the database) return null values, even though I haven't changed how I assign them. I have realised the problem is with this statement:

```
Vehicles = utc.Vehicles.OrderByDescending(v => v.DateCreated).Take(10).ToList()
```

It doesn't Include vehicle models and manufacturers. I am looking for a way to change this statement to:

```
Vehicles = utc.Vehicles.Include(v => v.Model).Include(v => v.Model.Manufacturer).OrderByDescending(v => v.DateCreated).Take(10).ToList()
```

But it throws an error and doesn't compile.

Can anyone assist?

**EDIT**
Here is my code. For the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
                        var home = new HomeViewModel
        {
            latestVehiclesViewModel = new LatestVehiclesViewModel 
            {
                Vehicles = utc.Vehicles.Include("Model").Include("Manufacturer")
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.DateCreated)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList()
            },

            searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel
            {
                Manufacturers = utc.Manufacturers.ToList(),
                //Models = utc.Models.ToList(),
            }
        };
        return View(home);
    }
```

For the model Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `return View(home);` what's `home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My EF5 doesn't allow me to pass an Expression as a parameter to DbSet().Include.

Try this rather:

```
Vehicles = utc.Vehicles.Include("Model").Include("Manufacturer")
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.DateCreated)
            .Take(10)
            .ToList()
```

Comment: This compiled, however I got a new error: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'UnderTrader.Models.Vehicle' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Manufacturer'.

Comment: then... perhaps it does not have the a navigation property called `Manufacturer`... but how would i know really seeing as you're the only one that has eyes on the .edmx, model classes, dbcontext class......post your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself... the new error was my fault, it should have been Include("Model.Manufacturer")... I have accepted Quinton Bernhardt's answer as that was what helped me to get this far in the first place... thank you.